# Updating PostgreSQL database from changes in Filemaker

Tags: postgresql, filemaker

I am able to import records into Filemaker using actualtech trial drives, but do not know how to update PostgreSQL database when making changes in Filemaker.

Ideally I would like Filemaker to remain as a front-end and PostgreSQL be the backend in the event they would like to move away from Filemaker.

Is there a real-time dynamic updating with ODBC connections?

Comment: This can already be done from within FileMaker. Check https://www.filemaker.com/support/technologies/sql.html. You're not just updating *from the data on FileMaker to PostgreSQL*, you actually use *from the FileMaker front-end* the data stored on *PostgreSQL*.

Comment: @joanolo, thank you.  I'm working with Actual's ESS driver now.  Just waiting to hear back about their license for Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some troubleshooting and biting the bullet... but I bought Open Source Driver from Actual Tech and it seems to be working.

Not very intuitive but I learned I can import records from postgreSQL using the "Open Source Driver" and I can then setup a relationship with the "ESS Driver" (File / Manage Database / Relationships ) to use postgreSQL as a backend; meaning updating real-time.

I would like to make a tutorial in the future because it was a few hours of trial and error.